# Notepad++ close non-whitespace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a Tweepy Stream Api json file that is included 33K tweets. All of them have non-whitespace space that I couldn't find solution. If you use copy and past it to pro.jsonlint.com, you can see that line 217 has "EOF" problem. I can fix them using notepad++ but first I need to understand that what is the problem and how I can fix it?

If somebody can tell me where is the EOF problem and how fix it with notepad++.

Thanks,

```
{
    "created_at": "Tue Mar 31 20:50:08 +0000 2015",
    "id": 583008398612029440,
    "id_str": "583008398612029440",
    "text": "RT @kamalakmustafa: Hain bir sald\u0131r\u0131 sonucu \u015fehit d\u00fc\u015fen Savc\u0131m\u0131z #MehmetSelimKiraz 'a Allah'tan rahmet, ailesine sab\u0131rlar diliyorum. Millet\u2026",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Windows Phone\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 1337409816,
        "id_str": "1337409816",
        "name": "Atakan \u00c7etin",
        "screen_name": "BrownnChild",
        "location": "",
        "url": null,
        "description": "Bir nefesine bile h\u00fckmedemedi\u011fimiz bu d\u00fcnya i\u00e7in boyun mu b\u00fckece\u011fiz? M\u0130LL\u0130 G\u00d6R\u00dc\u015e!",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 246,
        "friends_count": 116,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "favourites_count": 1077,
        "statuses_count": 2613,
        "created_at": "Mon Apr 08 19:31:06 +0000 2013",
        "utc_offset": 10800,
        "time_zone": "Athens",
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "lang": "tr",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "131516",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif",
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "profile_link_color": "009999",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/579347764670296064\/6yuzFJPG_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/579347764670296064\/6yuzFJPG_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1337409816\/1427653680",
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "retweeted_status": {
        "created_at": "Tue Mar 31 20:38:15 +0000 2015",
        "id": 583005408828252160,
        "id_str": "583005408828252160",
        "text": "Hain bir sald\u0131r\u0131 sonucu \u015fehit d\u00fc\u015fen Savc\u0131m\u0131z #MehmetSelimKiraz 'a Allah'tan rahmet, ailesine sab\u0131rlar diliyorum. Milletimizin ba\u015f\u0131 sa\u011folsun.",
        "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 338288811,
            "id_str": "338288811",
            "name": "Mustafa Kamalak",
            "screen_name": "kamalakmustafa",
            "location": "Ankara, T\u00fcrkiye",
            "url": "http:\/\/www.saadet.org.tr\/kisi\/mustafa-kamalak",
            "description": "Saadet Partisi Genel Ba\u015fkan\u0131\n Prof. Dr. Mustafa Kamalak",
            "protected": false,
            "verified": false,
            "followers_count": 52358,
            "friends_count": 2,
            "listed_count": 163,
            "favourites_count": 0,
            "statuses_count": 1574,
            "created_at": "Tue Jul 19 10:48:16 +0000 2011",
            "utc_offset": 10800,
            "time_zone": "Istanbul",
            "geo_enabled": false,
            "lang": "tr",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "is_translator": false,
            "profile_background_color": "FFFFFF",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000181217982\/FBktDfqo.jpeg",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000181217982\/FBktDfqo.jpeg",
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDFFCC",
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/436119860225908737\/76GmiIPj_normal.jpeg",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/436119860225908737\/76GmiIPj_normal.jpeg",
            "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/338288811\/1423922000",
            "default_profile": false,
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "following": null,
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "notifications": null
        },
        "geo": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "place": null,
        "contributors": null,
        "retweet_count": 122,
        "favorite_count": 152,
        "entities": {
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "text": "MehmetSelimKiraz",
                    "indices": [
                        45,
                        62
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "trends": [

            ],
            "urls": [

            ],
            "user_mentions": [

            ],
            "symbols": [

            ]
        },
        "favorited": false,
        "retweeted": false,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "filter_level": "low",
        "lang": "tr"
    },
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "text": "MehmetSelimKiraz",
                "indices": [
                    65,
                    82
                ]
            }
        ],
        "trends": [

        ],
        "urls": [

        ],
        "user_mentions": [
            {
                "screen_name": "kamalakmustafa",
                "name": "Mustafa Kamalak",
                "id": 338288811,
                "id_str": "338288811",
                "indices": [
                    3,
                    18
                ]
            }
        ],
        "symbols": [

        ]
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "tr",
    "timestamp_ms": "1427835008658"
}
{
    "created_at": "Tue Mar 31 20:50:08 +0000 2015",
    "id": 583008398649769984,
    "id_str": "583008398649769984",
    "text": "RT @BekirDeveli: #MehmetSelimKiraz",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitterhizmetcisi.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTranslation Mobile\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 1284184062,
        "id_str": "1284184062",
        "name": "K\u00fcrsad Celik",
        "screen_name": "KrsadC",
        "location": "Istanbul-Den\u0131zl\u0131",
        "url": null,
        "description": null,
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 166,
        "friends_count": 452,
        "listed_count": 1,
        "favourites_count": 1892,
        "statuses_count": 2723,
        "created_at": "Wed Mar 20 20:23:46 +0000 2013",
        "utc_offset": 10800,
        "time_zone": "Athens",
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "lang": "tr",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "FFF04D",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000168605771\/dgYo8Miy.jpeg",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000168605771\/dgYo8Miy.jpeg",
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "profile_link_color": "0099CC",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "F6FFD1",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/437899583348572160\/FamxSRwB_normal.jpeg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/437899583348572160\/FamxSRwB_normal.jpeg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1284184062\/1393238552",
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "retweeted_status": {
        "created_at": "Tue Mar 31 20:39:47 +0000 2015",
        "id": 583005791340404737,
        "id_str": "583005791340404737",
        "text": "#MehmetSelimKiraz",
        "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 607600160,
            "id_str": "607600160",
            "name": "Bekir Develi",
            "screen_name": "BekirDeveli",
            "location": "\u0130stanbul\/Turkey",
            "url": "http:\/\/www.bekirdeveli.com",
            "description": null,
            "protected": false,
            "verified": false,
            "followers_count": 225574,
            "friends_count": 2{
                "created_at": "Tue Mar 31 20:50:14 +0000 2015",
                "id": 583008421152198656,
                "id_str": "583008421152198656",
                "text": "#mehmetselimkiraz https:\/\/t.co\/ly9MROZ6Yg",
                "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/instagram.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eInstagram\u003c\/a\u003e",
                "truncated": false,
                "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
                "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
                "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
                "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
                "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
                "user": {
                    "id": 110186170,
                    "id_str": "110186170",
                    "name": "\u015eeyma Ceylan",
                    "screen_name": "cylnm",
                    "location": "ceylan",
                    "url": null,
                    "description": "\u0648\u0642\u062f\u0645 \u0643\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0646\u0632\u0639\u0627\u062c \u0631\u0627\u062d\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647I  http:\/\/Instagram.com\/seymaceylan_",
                    "protected": false,
                    "verified": false,
                    "followers_count": 1759,
                    "friends_count": 780,
                    "listed_count": 15,
                    "favourites_count": 7472,
                    "statuses_count": 9036,
                    "created_at": "Sun Jan 31 17:13:48 +0000 2010",
                    "utc_offset": -36000,
                    "time_zone": "Hawaii",
                    "geo_enabled": true,
                    "lang": "tr",
                    "contributors_enabled": false,
                    "is_translator": false,
                    "profile_background_color": "FF6699",
                    "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/866467818\/24dcf5a87af2b92f9ff76fead916e4ef.jpeg",
                    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/866467818\/24dcf5a87af2b92f9ff76fead916e4ef.jpeg",
                    "profile_background_tile": true,
                    "profile_link_color": "9266CC",
                    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
                    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "E5507E",
                    "profile_text_color": "362720",
                    "profile_use_background_image": true,
                    "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/574664598248419329\/Budj4Oq3_normal.jpeg",
                    "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/574664598248419329\/Budj4Oq3_normal.jpeg",
                    "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/110186170\/1410798690",
                    "default_profile": false,
                    "default_profile_image": false,
                    "following": null,
                    "follow_request_sent": null,
                    "notifications": null
                },
                "geo": null,
                "coordinates": null,
                "place": null,
                "contributors": null,
                "retweet_count": 0,
                "favorite_count": 0,
                "entities": {
                    "hashtags": [
                        {
                            "text": "mehmetselimkiraz",
                            "indices": [
                                0,
                                17
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "trends": [

                    ],
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/ly9MROZ6Yg",
                            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/05-6PQPQ-j\/",
                            "display_url": "instagram.com\/p\/05-6PQPQ-j\/",
                            "indices": [
                                18,
                                41
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "user_mentions": [

                    ],
                    "symbols": [

                    ]
                },
                "favorited": false,
                "retweeted": false,
                "possibly_sensitive": true,
                "filter_level": "low",
                "lang": "und",
                "timestamp_ms": "1427835014032"
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match individual JSON objects, and I think you can just match them and copy wherever you need using this regex:

```
\{(?:[^{}]+|(?0))*\}
```

It works in Notepad++ 6.7.5, and it will select the text from the first `{` up to the corresponding closing `}`.